# Send outgoing mail from docker container

Tags: postfix, smtp

We have installed and configured Postfix as a send only SMTP server to send only outgoing mails from the docker container in the same server. Now we want secure our SMTP server with user id and password. Can someone guide how to achieve this? Does setting up a send-only mail server without any authentication cause any security issues?

Please note that Postfix and SMTP server are running in the host system

Comment: Are Postfix and/or the SMTP server running inside the container or directly in the host system?

Comment: Postfix and SMTP server are running in the host system

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.